# Why is $P$(external) = $P$(internal) ± $\Delta P$?

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm in high school and am revising Thermodynamics. I'm not able to understand *where* this equation comes from;

P(external) = P(internal) ± dP (for reversible processes)

OR

P(external) = P(internal) ± ΔP (for irreversible processes)

I did understand the appropriate usage of the positive and the negative signs (before dP/ ΔP) for compression and expansion respectively, but I'm not able to understand the equation.

I believe this is a very simple doubt, so a little help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably some more context could help, but it looks like these two equations are just *definitions* of $\text d P$ or $\Delta P$.

Comment: Suppose you have a massless, frictionless piston.  If you apply Newton's 2nd law of motion to derive a force balance on the piston, how does the internal force compare with the external force?  Does it matter is the process is reversible or irreversible?  For an irreversible process, can the force per unit area exerted by the gas on the piston be calculated using the ideaal gas law?

Comment: @pppqqq We were just dictated this under 'reversible and irreversible processes'. And then my teacher just told us the different signs for Delta P during expansion and compression accordingly.

Comment: @ChetMiller I'm assuming the external and internal pressure would be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term pressure is reserved for an isotropic state of compressive stress in which the gas compressive stress acts equally in all directions.  This is the case in a reversible expansion or compression.

However, in an irreversible expansion or compression, the gas compressive stress does not act equally in all directions. We can still call the compressive stress averaged over all directions "pressure," but, for an irreversible expansion, the compressive stress exerted by the gas on the piston is less than the average compressive stress (the pressure), and for an irreversible compression, compressive stress exerted by the gas on the piston is greater than the average compressive stress (i.e., the pressure).  The difference between the reversible and irreversible cases is the result of viscous stresses within the gas which depend, not on the amount of gas expansion, but on the *rate* of gas expansion.  In a reversible process, the rate of expansion approaches zero.

Therefore, in irreversible expansions and compressions, the ideal gas law cannot be used to calculate the compressive stress on the piston.  The ideal gas law will give the wrong answer for the compressive stress on the piston.  There is a fundamental difference in the behavior of the gas when it experiences irreversible expansions and compressions compared to when the deformation is reversible.